# How to join multiple channels in qwebirc?

Tags: irc

I'm using http://webchat.freenode.net/

It uses http://qwebirc.org/features that supports:

> Multiple channels and queries.

I try typing: `join super-fancy-channel`

I got either:

```
[11:39] Can't use this command in this window
```

Or:

```
[11:40] <stefek99> join super-fancy-channel
[11:40] <stefek99> (screw me - I'm using webchat.freenode.net - and I want to have multiple channels in tabs)
```

So if you happen to know how to connect to multiple channels - let me know!
Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands usually have a slash in front and channels a hash in front.

If you are connected to IRC, then to join a channel you would type:

```
/join #super-fancy-channel
```